# htaccess rule..not able to solve

Tags: .htaccess

i am struggling to get my site htaccess work... but no luck..

below is the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  /profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
 </IfModule>
```

this works fine no issues.. but when i add something it will not work.. in following cases -

1) For example when i type example.com/dinesh  it will redirect me to  www.example.com (always home page instead i want it to be www.example.com/dinesh

2) now i have another users.php with two parameters the thing is when i pass one parameter it should execute this rule profile.php but when i pass two parameters then it should take me to user.php i tried so many combination but this is not working.

if any expert can give me atleast some tips that will be great.

Comment: Same question as always: have you turned on rewrote logging? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

As for **1)**, it probably doesn't have anything to do with the above rules. If `/dinesh` exists, you should look in there. If it doesn't exist, you should look into `/profile.php`, that's probably what's redirecting you to the home page.

As for **2)**, your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  /profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
```

Matches the URI: `/something/else`, because the regular expression doesn't have an end-of-string match. It matches the first `something`, and that's good enough. If you add a `$` to the end, it won't match `/something/else`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  /profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
```

Or, you can place the other rule that routes to `user.php` *before* the one that routes to profile. but it's better to have the `$`.